# Android - draw gif with AnimatedImageDrawable on canvas

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am currently trying to paint a gif onto my canvas in a viewSurface.My code so far looks like this:

```
    val victorySource = ImageDecoder.createSource(context.assets, "victory.gif")
    victoryGif = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(victorySource) as AnimatedImageDrawable
    canvas = holder.lockCanvas()
    victoryGif.start()
    victoryGif.draw(canvas)
    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
```

But this will only draw the first picture of the Gif. Does anyone know how to properly draw a gif on a canvas (it doesn't matter if the answer is in Java or Kotlin)?

Answer (score 0):

Call it from `Runnable` like this

```
   val liveHandler = Handler()
        val runnable = Runnable { 
        animationDrawble?.draw(canvas)
        animationDrawble?.start()
        runnable?.let { liveHandler?.postDelayed(it, 1000L / 25L) 
        
 }
```